# Having trouble getting a bind variable to work in Oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I'm trying to create a bind variable, but the results say that I have no data found even though I know that what I'm entering into my variable matches with a row in my data.

This is what I've typed out:

```
SELECT first_name AS "First Name", last_name AS "Last Name" 
FROM sales_representatives
WHERE id = :commission_rate 
ORDER BY last_name ASC;
```

Comment: We need more context. How is this invoked? Where is it? When are you setting session state for :commission_rate?

Comment: I ended up solving this by replacing using the id in the where statement and just using the commission_rate, so that the where clause reads as WHERE commission_rate = :commission_rate. Not 100% sure how this works, but it worked for me.

Comment: well, that's changing your filter. as long as it matches your requirements, you're all good.

Answer (score 0):

In apex the page items are the bind variables. So if your report on the sales_representatives table/view is on page 1, your bind variable would be a page item P1_COMMISSION_RATE. The "P1_" prefix is a naming convention that is used in apex and that you should stick to. You can set the value of the page item in many places. 
To see a very simple example of a report with a bind variable, install the apex sample app "Sample Reporting" and check out the classic report. It implements a select list with a report. The report has a single bind variable.
--Koen